# PHP and HTML Code after while loop not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, bootstrap-4

I have designed a form and a dropdown that fetches its option from MYSQL Database. But after getting the options the rest of the code like the button and other parts disappeared not showing. The rest of the code works fine every time I comment out the PHP Query.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <label><b>Add Student to this User ID</b></label>
  <select name="student_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">--Select Student--</option>
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY first_name, last_name, Other_name ASC");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . ' ' . $row['Other_name'] ?></option>;
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-4">
      <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" name="submit" value="Add Student"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the exact HTML returned to the client after the server-side code runs?  Is the PHP code producing an error?  Now is a good opportunity for you to start doing some debugging to narrow down what's happening.

Comment: Open up the source in the browser, and double-check the generated HTML to check for syntax errors.

Comment: You should view source to see the error. But the error is probably the lack of semi colons at the end of each echo in the while loop.

Comment: If you have no PHP errors the problem could be an HTML error, sanitize the database values removing quotes, double quotes and angle brackets.

Answer (score 0):

There's a semicolon missing after `$row['Other_name']`